# Is there a way to stop recording screen with Byzanz?

Tags: animated-gif, screencast

I use tool called byzanz to record my screen and create gif files.

This is the way I use it:

```
byzanz-record -d 55 --delay=2 -x 0 -y 0 -w 3940 -h 950 desktop-animation.gif
```

However, often I can't tell in advance how long the recording will be so it ends up with awkward moments at the end or prematurely ending the recording. Is there a way how to tell byzanz to stop its job, perhaps by sending a signal to it with kill or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be an option that could achieve that :

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/byzanz-record.1.html

> -e, --exec=COMMAND
>                 Instead of specifying the duration of the animation, execute the
>                 given COMMAND and record until the command exits. This is useful
>                 both  for  benchmarking and to use more complex ways to stop the
>                 recording, like writing scripts that listen on dbus.

However, in my package manager with the latest byzanz (fedora), --exec doesn't exist.

I think with that option, you could do :

```
byzanz-record --exec 'sleep 1000000' --delay=2 -x 0 -y 0 -w 3940 -h 950 desktop-animation.gif
```

and when you want to stop the recording, do : `killall sleep`

Sidenote: I have opened an issue on redhat bugzilla tracker to update their byzanz-record version : https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1531055